# iPhone provesion Provision Profile outdated no renew button

Tags: iphone

Do you have to renew the Provision Profile  before it becomes outdated? I do not see a renew button in the Provision Profile   portal.  Allso if I creat a new Provision Profile   can I use it to update my app instad of the new one?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can renew from the XCode Organizer. Open the xcode organizer to the Devices Tab. From the source list if you select the "Provisioning Profile" you should see all the Profiles. Each profile has a "renew" button next to it. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Thanks,
Nirumal.
[image]

Comment: There is no renew button - there is only a general refresh button that loads all your profiles from provisioning portal.

Comment: Yeah and now read the question: _before it becomes outdated?_ ;-) I know that there is a button when it is outdated. but not before that. If you want to renew them before you need to go to provisioning portal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply editing a profile in iOS Provisioning Portal at developer.apple.com updates the profile . It is renewed and works again one year.

This works not for Distribution profiles, they are renewed when you purchase the program for an additional year.

Of course you can also create new profiles but then you may need to update all your developer iPhones with the new profile. A simple way is using Xcode to manage your Profiles especially the iOS Team Provisioning Profile.